# Is there a way to return all non-null values even if one is null in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, null

The statement I've got is

```
select coalesce(A||','||B||','||C) into D
```

If C is null, then D will = < NULL >, but  if I remove C and just have A and B, then D will = the values of A & B.  There may be situations where any one of those is NULL and I still want to return any non-null values into D - is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `concat_ws()` instead:

```
select concat_ws(',', a, b, c)
```

Comment: thank you!  Is it possible to do combine it with `||','||` or `||'&'||` - I know it's a little bit janky but the DB (which I have no control over) lists multiple items per column so without that it'll insert as `A=valueOfA,valueOfB` instead of `A=valueOfA, B=valueOfB`.  Thanks! :)