# How to use concat_ws() to return multiple values into different keys: PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, null, concatenation

Related to this [Is there a way to return all non-null values even if one is null in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218467/is-there-a-way-to-return-all-non-null-values-even-if-one-is-null-in-postgresql) - the solution of which allowed me to return null values, however it returns it into the same key instead of the one assigned.

For this example in particular so I'd like to insert it as `A=valueOfA, B=valueOfB` instead of `A=valueOfA,valueOfB`.

```
    select concat_ws(",", A, B, C) into D;
    // if C is null, it will return A=valueOfA,valueOfB
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Why invent some new syntax if there is JSON which is quite easy to generate?

Comment: sorry to trouble, but would you be able to provide an example - I'm still pretty new to PSQL and I had a look online, but not too sure where to start :( thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to simply generate a JSON value:

```
jsonb_build_object('a', a, 'b', b, 'c', c)
```

This would e.g. include `"a": null` if column `a` was null. If you want to remove those, use `jsonb_strip_nulls`:

```
jsonb_strip_nulls(jsonb_build_object('a', a, 'b', b, 'c', c))
```